# How to trigger a github action only when a tag is pushed and after a workflow is completed

Tags: github, github-actions, pipeline

I want to trigger a release github action only when these two conditions are true:

- I push a new tag
- The test github action (unit tests) was successfully run

This is what I tried:

```
name: Semantic Release

on:
    push:
        tags:
            - 'v*'
    workflow_run:
        workflows:
            - "test"   # basically i have another test action to run unit tests
        types:
            - completed
jobs:
    release:
        name: "Release on Pypi"
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        concurrency: release

        steps:
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v2
                with:
                    fetch-depth: 0

            -   name: Python Semantic Release
                uses: relekang/python-semantic-release@master
                with:
                    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
                    repository_username: __token__
                    repository_password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_TOKEN }}
```

I set my test action to trigger when I push to master, which is working fine. However, the release action is always triggered after the test action even when I do not push a new tag.

I want the release action to trigger only when I push a new tag and wait for the test action to complete successfully. Why is my example is not working in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are treated as 2 separate triggers - they combine as `OR` not `AND`. So in your case, it's either a `tag push` or `workflow_run completed`.

There is no way to filter out `workflow_run` trigger by tag I'm afraid.

How I would solve this is to trigger your Semantic release directly from  your `Test` workflow using workflow dispatch event:

```
- name: Invoke workflow in another repo with inputs
  uses: benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1
  with:
    workflow: Semantic Release
    repo: yourcompany/yourrepo
```

You have to make your Semantic Release to be triggered by `workflow_dispatch` first to make it work:

```
on:
    workflow_dispatch
```